# VS Code sign in using Azure Account Extention from Azure VM

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using  VM(Ubuntu server 1804) of Azure(Japan region).

How to reproduce:

Install xrdp, xfce4 using apt-get, and successfully login to the VM via Remote Desktop.  After installed firefox, I installed Visual Studio Code, and installed Azoure Account Extention(0.4.3)

then tried to login to my azure account.
After click [OPEN] button on popped up dialog with message "To sign in, use web brower to open.... enter the code GPJXXXXX to authenticate.".
A borwser was opend (Firefox), and type the code , then clicked "Continue" botton.

Select the account listed in the dialog (Pick an account)
Type my e-mail address and my password.
Click "Sign in with your phone or token device"
Answer for the phone, and type pincode.
A browser was changed to new message "you have signed in to the Visual Studio Code applicaton on your device, you may close this weindow."

Start playing with VS code again, and try to select subscriptions (Azure: Select Subscriptions"),

VS code display Pop up dialog with following message.
"Not signed in , sign in first.  (Source: Azure Account Extention)".

Is there any setting should I do to run VS code can on a Azure VM?

Comment: I have the exact same problem - trying to deploy an angular 6 app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following: File->Preferences->Settings, then click "Azure configuration" and add your Azure tenant id.

Comment: That works! To find your tenant id go to https://portal.azure.com/ and type tenant in the top search box.